# Passing existing object instances as constructor parameters to the ObjectDataProvider in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to pass existing object instances as parameters to the constructor of an object being created using the ObjectDatatProvider.  This always fails with the given exception, even though my object has a constructor that takes one parameter:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 34 :
>   ObjectDataProvider cannot create
>   object; Type='VegaViewModel';
>   Error='Wrong parameters for
>   constructor.'
>   MissingMethodException:'System.MissingMethodException:
>   Constructor on type
>   'WpfApplication1.VegaViewModel' not
>   found.    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags
>   bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[]
>   args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo
>   culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.ObjectDataProvider.CreateObjectInstance(Exception&
>   e)'

Here is my Xaml:

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type WpfApplication1:VegaModel}" MethodName="Sample" x:Key="VegaPnlData"/>     
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type WpfApplication1:VegaViewModel}" x:Key="VegaViewModel">
                <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource VegaPnlData}"/>
               </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

If I use this xaml I get the same error as well:

```
 <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type WpfApplication1:VegaViewModel}" x:Key="VegaViewModel">
            <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="VegaPnlData"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
```

Here is the code for the VegaViewModel class:

```
public class VegaViewModel
{            
    public VegaViewModel(VegaModel vegaPnl)
    {
        VegaPnl = vegaPnl;           
    }

    public VegaModel VegaPnl { get; set; }            
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an `ObjectDataProvider` via the `ConstructorParameters`. The reason as [Dr. WPF adequately states](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c7fbe40a-0e22-47df-8031-8a4a76d5b329/)...

> An ObjectDataProvider (ODP) is
>   designed to be used with a Binding. 
>   If you use it outside of the context
>   of a binding, you end up refering to
>   an instance of the ODP rather than the
>   dereferenced object that it
>   "provides".

Your trying to do something the framework won't allow by design.

Comment: So how do I bind to the result of the method and use that as the parameter to the constructor?

Comment: If I do the following I still get the same exception:

Comment: @user583337 You can't do it in your current implementation. Check out the link I posted as Dr. WPF provides alternatives which should suit you. Pushing all this into the XAML is in and of itself a bit strange to be honest...but assuming you have a valid reason to do it.

Comment: How would one go about passing the window/user control object as a parameter to the constructor parameters.  I'd like my window's data object to have a reference to the window object.